# JPA query not returning the same results as query in log

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple JPA query which I use like this (ProcessDetailCategory is a string value enum):

```
List<ProcessDetail> currentProcessDetails = processDetailRepository.findByProcessIdAndProcessDetailCategoryAndProcessFileNotNull(process.getId(), ProcessDetailCategory.LIST_ELEMENT);
```

I have query logging enabled:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: TRACE
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

The log says

```
Hibernate: select processdet0_.id as id1_66_, processdet0_.process_id as process_4_66_, processdet0_.process_detail_category as process_2_66_, processdet0_.process_file_id as process_3_66_, processdet0_.url_link as url_link5_66_ from process_details processdet0_ where processdet0_.process_id=? and processdet0_.process_detail_category=? and (processdet0_.process_file_id is not null)
```

formatted:

```
HIBERNATE:

SELECT processdet0_.id                      AS id1_66_,
   processdet0_.process_id              AS process_4_66_,
   processdet0_.process_detail_category AS process_2_66_,
   processdet0_.process_file_id         AS process_3_66_,
   processdet0_.url_link                AS url_link5_66_
FROM   process_details processdet0_
WHERE  processdet0_.process_id = ?
   AND processdet0_.process_detail_category = ?
   AND ( processdet0_.process_file_id IS NOT NULL )
```

When I run this query on the db manually I get results, but the JPA query returns none. No, I'm not querying the wrong db, everything else works just fine.

Comment: Can you share code block which calls your method : `findByProcessIdAndProcessDetailCategoryAndProcessFileNotNull`

Comment: @EmreSavcı just edited the question

Comment: Do you have some environment specific config in application.yaml? Is it possible to you run app on some test environment?

Comment: @EmreSavcı the config i posted is in my active dev config (application-dev.yaml), which overrides the global config

Comment: Are you sure that you use the same parameters in jpa-query and db-console? `logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE` will show you parameters values. How is the enum mapped?

Comment: @AnatolySamoylenko the enum is mapped like this:
     @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
also its logging the id param, but not the enum, why is that?

Comment: @icguy it's ok. `BasicBinder` (logging property) not apply to Enums. They can be seen in the logs if you implement `AttributeConverter <ProcessDetailCategory, String>` for Enum (then you can remove the `@Enumerated` annotation) - this is a another approach with enums using.

Regarding your main question: show us the `ProcessDetail` class with mappings.